# Datatable overflow hidden overwrite?

Tags: css, datatable, datatables

I have this column added in Datatable with a pop out menu and it gets hidden behind Datatable's native #dataTables_scrollBody div. If I set overflow visible, the table overflows and breaks out of the window width in small screens.

How can I add the dropdown menu shown in the example which will show up on top? Z-index has no effect.

Dropdown parent element position set to relative and the dropwon UL css is-

```
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 0;
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 15px 25px;
background-color: #ececec;
z-index: 999;
```

[image: Demonstration of the problem]
How to achieve this please? And can I change the data reorder arrows and add some my own icons?

Comment: You have a very local problem difficult or impossible to reproduce. Please provide an example showing the exact behavior, you can use this fiddle as a starting point -> **http://jsfiddle.net/0f9Ljfjr/985/**

Comment: Hi, I updated the fiddle and the problem is gone...it works but in the local project I have, this vertical scrollbar appears when the dropdown is opend and the bottom part hides behind. Any idea what might be the reason? I tinkered with z-index but no luck. Image link of the fiddle with problem show...I hope it's clear.
https://imgur.com/a/LlcLo